# I want to use webdriverwait for the element which is currently not present in DOM

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

In my script am adding appointment and after appointment got saved in the top the screen the tool tip appears with a text "Saved Successfully". I am Asserting this text, i tried with `Thread.sleep(3000);` but my script got succeed only sometimes not all the time. Now i want to use webdriverwait for this tooltip element which is currently not presented in the DOM but it will appear once when the appointment got saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverWait class, eg.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

This is just an example. For more information please look in http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebDriverWait which is the standard way in Selenium to "wait" for something to happen, eg Title changed to a specific text, an element disappeared, etc..

For your specific case, I usually define the following method to detect if a tag contains a specific text exists in document body:

```
private static true IsElementExistsWithText(string text, string tagName, IWebDriver driver)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(string.Format("{0}:contains(\"{1}\")", tagName, text)));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Then in my code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until((d) => { return IsElementExistsWithText("Saved Successfully", "span", driver); });
```